# How to AJAX in a Form

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have created a form in ASP.NET using C#. Now I want to implement AJAX on it.

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZ9H.png)   to see the form.

I have used a GridView to show the saved information.
I have absolutely no idea what to do and from where to start.
If someone could guide me how to do it...?

Comment: There is too many tutorials which can help you to bind data in gridview using ajax. Your link is not working which you have recommend in question. But you can followup using this link. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-data-to-GridView-with-jQuery-or-JSON-in-ASPNet.aspx or if you want crud you can follow up http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/145c93/crud-operation-using-ajax-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

write "onClick" function like:

onClick="myClick()";

define this click in your js file like:

```
   function myClick(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
//to get response on the html
   }
  };
 xhttp.open("GET/post", "urltocall", true);
   xhttp.send();
}
```